# How do I detect whether any contact forms have been created?

Tags: 8

**Context:** On my Drupal 8 site I'm trying to add in a new section containing a view that lists out all forms. The user can then click on one of the form and it launches a download of all the messages sent through that form. However that section should only be visible if the user has created at least 1 form.

**What I've tried:** So far what I've discovered is that the contact forms are stored in the config table in the database, so I could theoretically run a query like "SELECT 1 FROM config WHERE name LIKE '%contact.form%'" or whatever the equivalent in D8 is. However, it seems like there has to be a quicker way to return either the presence of contact forms or the contact forms themselves programmatically.

**Final question:** How can I return either the contact forms themselves or at least a boolean representing the presence of contact forms programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [D8 config factory interface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Config%21ConfigFactoryInterface.php/interface/ConfigFactoryInterface/9.0.x) to retrieve multiple contact form config keys and their corresponding config entities:

```
$contact_form_keys = \Drupal::configFactory()->listAll('contact.form');
$contact_form_configs = \Drupal::configFactory()->:loadMultiple($contact_form_keys);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much